# Sharing app-IDs among multiple developer account

Tags: iphone, app-store, push

I have an apple developer account using which I have developed an application for one of my clients. Now, the client also has a developer account. Is there anyway, I can create an app ID like com.client.* in the clients developer account and then upload an application's release version using an appID like com.mycompany.applicationname which is created in my developer account.

Or else, there is no option like that??

Answer (score 0):

An app ID is a unique application identifier.  Even the exact same source code, built with two different app ID's, would be considered two completely different applications.

In order for you to compile your client's application, you will need to get a copy of their profile using com.client.* and compile the application as com.client.appname.

Answer (score 0):

That would be possible, (as far as I know, apple doesn't check the AppIDs if they are used anywhere yet outside of your program) but might get problems when submitting to the appstore and furthermore, you could not submit with his account, what he probably wants. Here's what we usually do:
 1. Create a  *. Provising profile for yourself for development purposese.
 3. For push notifications, you should be able to create a DEV certfiicate with Appid  com.client.appname in your developer program
 4. Have your customer invite you into his Program and create the matching provising profile for appstore submission and push notification with this Appid.

You can be in multiple development programs (I'm currently in three different ones..)